# Compiler for Windows 7 with a GUI?

Tags: windows-7, python, c++, c#, ruby

I'm trying to learn a programming language to make a simple 2D space game or an RPG, but I am very stuck as to what one to use. I think I have narrowed it down to Python or Ruby, but there seem to be thousands of different versions of even those - all with different features! At the moment I'm finding it really hard to even get as far as installing something and trying out an example, and I am getting really very frustrated with it.

What I would really, really love is a good modern compiler for a powerful user-friendly language that comes with a proper interface (including a file tree for my program and a really helpful and specific debugger). The language has to be written with beginners in mind, but scale to experts. It would be a lot of help if it had a large amount of online support, friendly tutorials that aren't written by academics, and lots of good extensions. It also needs to be closed-source as I'd like to make a sell-able game eventually.

If possible I'd really love one that can compile the same code for different platforms automatically and it would also be a huge help if it wasn't case sensitive! :D

My previous experience is some basic HTML and CSS editing in Dreamweaver, but I've tried Visual Basic and loved the user-friendly interface. If possible I would like a compiler along those sorts of lines and I am happy to consider any language at all if someone can make a case for it. I am very wary of VB itself, however, as its tutorials seem to assume you already know at least one programming language and so far I haven't found a way to make any code examples work inside VB.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

"I think I have narrowed it down to Python or Ruby, but there seem to be thousands of different versions of even those" - I don't know Ruby, but Python only has two versions 2.x and 3.x. Use the latest 3.x if you want to.

The free [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) community edition IDE is excellent (JetBrains, who make it, sell many excellent IDEs), and has all of the debug features which you will require

[image]

---

You say "it would also be a huge help if it wasn't case sensitive". I can't why, but it's your choice.

Personally, I prefer compiled to interpreted languages, so the obvious solution would seem to be Pascal.  The [Lazarus  IDE](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/). It uses Free Pascal, a GPL'ed compiler that runs on Linux, Win32, OS/2, 68K and more.

I has a drag & drop form designer like Delphi, or Visual Studio, and a great debugger. Plus, it is free.

[This page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Application_Gallery) shows several dozen applciations which were created by Lazarus, to give you a feel for what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

On seeing your question you are on windows you need a compiler(the best) and good user interface then I will stick with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community edition( since it is free ) and has excellent compiler and support for C++ and Python can also be integrated along with it, advanced debugging tools like immediate window, ease break point creating and monitoring etc., are there. C# is owned by Microsoft by the so there may not be any need to explain more on this (since both are owned by MS it would be the best) I don't have experience with Ruby and there are no IDE which supports every language in the world(at-least to my knowledge)

Comment: Python works in VB? Cool! Do you know if Ruby might work as I have just today found this cool site called tryruby.org and I've been having fun on the interactive command line thing.

Comment: I have found a version of Ironruby that can be imported into VB 2010, but I have VB 2015, so it probably won't work.

Comment: At the moment, I am veering away from C++ because of the complexity and memory management issues. Would you still recommend it?

Comment: @Hadashi, I cannot recommend any single language. what I would say is a language may not be suited for purpose for e.g web-scrapping can be done easily using Python but it is not usually done using C++ and drivers are usually written in C++. So it don't mean web-scrapping is impossible in C++ or drivers cannot be written in Python. It is just not suitable for a purpose. So I would recommend to pick a language which best suites for your purpose